# What is the meaning of ‘on his corner’?

Tags: meaning

I see the sentence in my book : There will be an accident on his corner one day.

May you tell me what is the meaning of :’on his corner’?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to say without further context, but the most *likely* interpretation (because it doesn't have a different explicit context in the one sentence) uses the following definition of *corner*:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 b** : the place of intersection of two streets or roads

In other words:

> There will be an accident on the street near where he lives (or works) one day.

Perhaps, for instance, it's a heavily trafficked intersection that doesn't have a traffic light.

Comment: In my homework book, it is just a sentence along, which does not have any context.